# Is it possible to split a form into multiple erb modules?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a large form with multiple tabs and would like to be able to split it into multiple modules and include each as a partial. Something like:

main.html.erb:

```
  <%= form_for (@myobject) do |f| %>
       <%= render "module1" %>
       ....
```

module1.html.erb:

```
 <%= f.text_field :field1 %>
 ...
```

Needless to say, when I do it like this I get an error from module1 that "f" is undefined.
Is there a way to split form fields into multiple modules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  You should pass the `f` as a local to the `module1` partial:

```
<%= form_for (@myobject) do |f| %>
   <%= render "module1", f: f %>
```

Then you should be able to use `f` in your `module1` partial.

Comment: What to do when I want to use myobject in module1 too. I always get the error undefined local variable or method `myobject' for #<#<Class:0x007f8486864090>:0x007f848455b030>
Did you mean?  @myobject